# @IBOutlet in awakeFromNib not initialized

Tags: ios, swift

I was pretty sure that `@IBOutlet` was initialized after `super.awakeFromNib()` but it is nil?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new sub UIView; MyView
2. Create a .xib UIView and set "File's Owner" to "MyView"
3. In Storyboard in a UIViewController's view set "Custom Class" to MyView.
4. Connect the `@IBOutlet`
5. This will give you the error. 4.

Update:

 This does work if you are using Storyboard directly.

1. Create a sub UIView; MyView
2. In Storyboard UIViewController view add a label.
3. In Storyboard in a UIViewController's view set "Custom Class" to MyView
4. Connect the `@IBOutlet`
5. This works.

   ```
   import UIKit

   class MyView: UIView {

   @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       self.myLabel.text = "Hello world"
   }

   override func didMoveToSuperview() {
       self.myLabel.text = "Hello world"
   }

   override func layoutSubviews() {
       self.myLabel.text = "Hello world"
   }

   override func didMoveToWindow() {
       self.myLabel.text = "Hello world"        
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: Are you sure the outlet is connected?

Comment: Same: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Who owns the navigation bar? If it's a top-level nib object then you need to connect a strong reference to it, otherwise it will be deallocated by the time you reach awakeFromNib.

Comment: A `UIView` should not know about a `UINavigationBar`. Review your architecture.

Comment: The file's owner should not be a `UIView`; it should be whatever your `UIView` subclass is.

Comment: Right, typo - thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storyboard does not load xibs. You have to load the xib explicitly inside your view. The storyboard creates the views using `init(coder:)`:

```
func loadNib() -> UIView? {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    guard
        let nibName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)).components(separatedBy: ".").last,
        let views = bundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil),
        let contentView = views.first as? UIView
    else {
        return nil
    }

    return contentView
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let contentView = self.loadNib()!
    self.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
}
```

This will load the root view of the xib, adding it to the view. Since we are passing `self` as the owner, the outlets will be connected.